# Can I use a ptr_vector as heap?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, heap, ptr-vector

I would like to replace a std:vector which is used as a heap (sort_heap) with a ptr_vector.
The author of ptr_vector on http://sourceforge.net/projects/ptr-vector/ mentions that using std namespace sort algorithms is not a good idea as this would lead to a movement of objects instead of pointers. He refers to stdx:sort... algorithms which are apparently built into the sourceforge version (dating back to 2006).
I cannot find the latter in the boost implementation of ptr_vector.
So if I rely on a boost ptr_vector (how) can I use the container with sort_heap without sacrificing performance ?